# Json deserialize, put empty elements to array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

when someone sends invalid JSON to my webapi :

```
"items" : [
        ,
        {               
            ...
        }
]
```

then the deserialization doesn't fail and puts a "null" value as the first element of array, is it possible to let the json deserialiser fail and return an error? or just remove null elements from the array.
I already have tried adding a converter where I can remove empty elements, but I can't find source, how existing array (de)serialization works.

i found MassTransit.Serialization.ListJsonConverter which can deserialize List/Array, so i override it call base deserialize method and check result if it contains null values just throw exception, but for me it's strange that Newtonsoft.Json doesn't contain Array converter

as it is for webapi i don't want to parse anything by myself so only possible solution to extend current deserialization methods

Comment: one reason might've been which your Json is not in a correct format

Comment: Valkyriee is right, the better way would be to to remove the cause for the corrupted data, not to deal with it.

Comment: i know that it's incorrect, but deserializer do not fail and server error is not good responce to invalid json, so it should send back error responce with proper description where is mistake in json or just thow out null elements

Comment: i found MassTransit.Serialization.ListJsonConverter which can deserialize List/Array, so i override it and check result if it contains null values just throw exception, but for me it's strange that Newtonsoft.Json doesn't contain Array converter

Comment: You could use a selecttoken query then throw and exception if any elements with null are found.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm

Answer (score -1):

In relation to your comment.
You can parse the json string like this:

```
string jsonString = "SOME JSON STRING";
try
{
    JsonValue.Parse(jsonString);
}
catch (FormatException fex)
{
    //handle formatting exceptions
}
catch (Exception ex) //some other exception
{
    //handle other exceptions
}
```

On FormatException you can return some valuable response.

Comment: The problem is that the current code with the shown input doesn't throw an exception.